# Выполнение PHP скрипта CRON

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

У меня есть php файл, который создает файл в директории. Если обратиться к нему напрямую через адресную строку, то все отрабатывает. Выполняю команду через планировщик, отрабатывает без ошибок, однако файл не создается.

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/www-root/data/www/test.ru/wp-content/themes/shablon/csv.php
```

Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: все пути в скрипте должны быть абсолютными

Comment: @Ипатьев 
Поменял путь в скрипте, но  результата нет
fopen('/var/www/www-root/data/www/test.ru/export/dump.csv', 'w');

Comment: тупой вопрос, если руками запускать, то скрипт выполняется?

Comment: Скрипт в кроне запускается от того же пользователя, под которым работает веб-сервер?

Comment: > выполняется, если убрать абсолютный путь
> скрипт запускает root

Comment: разрешение на запись в папку есть у root?

Comment: да, указал путь fopen('dump.csv', 'w+'), файл появился в корневой папке root, его можно переместить в нужную папку используя абсолютный путь, однако если его в php указать, то файл найти не могу

Comment: Логирование крона включено у вас?